# Is it necessary to have separate class file for dictionary object in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, aspxgridview

I was learning dictionary object where I reached a point there developer has added new class file to declare variable to show them into gridview. So I want to ask that `Is it necessary to have separate class file for dictionary object in ASP.Net ?

Comment: what you're asking is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to have a separate file.
You can do that if it helps to organize your code.